# Strange issues when loading JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, dll, jogl

I've been getting this Java runtime error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jogl in java.library.path`

This is to do with having difficulty loading the dependent native libraries required to use Java OpenGL. It's an issue that's all over the net; there are some dependent files that need to be on the classpath. I've tried following the `java -Djava.library.path "path/to/dir"` method of registering the DLLs but it hasn't seemed to help. I think it may be because I'm trying to run this application within the Netbeans IDE.

What's odd is that I've downloaded the Netbeans JOGL plugin and their example application which shows off some basic OpenGL functions perfectly! I've searched through the code and there's no custom DLL loading, nor is there any project-specific configuration settings that I can see. I have no idea what's going on!

Comment: How are you loading it?  Another questioner encountered a similar issue a few days ago because he/she used `System.load` instead of the correct `System.loadLibrary`.

Comment: I've read that I shouldn't have to do that explicitly if the runtime environment is configured correctly. What's really getting to me is that all of these other JOGL applications run fine. I think what I'm unfortunately going to have to do is work around the issue by just using one of the example projects and building my code into that. I'd really like to understand what's going on!

Comment: Did you try using `loadLibrary` instead of `load`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to jogamp.org's JOGL, please have a look at our [Wiki page for IDEs](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE).

Thx to our [automated native JAR library loading](http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/userguide/index.html#automatednativelibraryloading), 
you don't even have to set a native library path at all.

Works well w/ Eclipse - and as I heard w/ Netbeans too.

Pls don't forget to attach the source zip file to the matching gluegen/jogl
jar file, so you can benefit from our javadoc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It's a very clever system that you've implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting of example application.
For example, in eclipse you should add jars into build path (which can be accessed from project settings)

Also u can try this plugin: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/11451/addtolibrary

Comment: The way I worked around it was by loading up an example project using the Netbeans JOGL plugin tool and just built my application into that. It must be that when using Netbeans, it references some localised implementation of OpenGL.